# How to make the quadrangles can do drag and drop in Unity Editor Window?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to create an interactive GUI object in Unity - **Editor Window**?

[image]

I can draw the static quadrangle like code below. But I want the effect like the [reference video](https://youtu.be/5PPeofVU_gU?t=22s) that starts from `0:22` to `0:30`.

```
public class EditorCanvas {
    public static void DrawQuad(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
        Rect rect = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        texture.SetPixel(0, 0, color);
        texture.Apply();
        GUI.skin.box.normal.background = texture;
        GUI.Box(rect, GUIContent.none);
    }
}


public class MyWindow : EditorWindow {
    void OnGUI() {
        EditorCanvas.DrawQuad(100, 75, 50, 50, Color.black);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a rect which contains the current position of your box. In this example the position is initialized to `0,0` for a size of `100,100`.

Then for each time you move the mouse while clicking ([EventType.MouseDrag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventType.MouseDrag.html)) you add the mouse movement since the last event ([Event.delta](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event-delta.html)) to the box position.

In order to get a smoothly drag & drop you have to tell to unity that you have an event so he can repaint. ([Event.use](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event.Use.html))

```
Rect _boxPos =  new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);

void OnGUI()
{
    if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDrag &&
        _boxPos.Contains(Event.current.mousePosition))
    {
        _boxPos.position += Event.current.delta;
    }

    GUI.Box(_boxPos, "test");

    if (Event.current.isMouse)
        Event.current.Use();
}
```

So now you can easily adapt your DrawQuad method.